# Jquery getJSON not working, but ajax does

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have an issue that is bugging me, though it is not stopping me since I have a work-around. I'm trying to do an ajax call to a page method I have on an aspx page. I need to get json back, but the WebMethod `GetGender` is never called, unless I use an `$.ajax` call.

So, this WORKS:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "StudentFunctions.aspx/GetGender",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(msg.d);
            var options = {
              title: 'Gender',
              height: '5000px'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
```

But, none of the below work:

```
$.get("StudentFunctions.aspx/GetGender", function(msg) { 
        alert(msg)
     }, "json");

$.post("StudentFunctions.aspx/GetGender", function(msg) { 
        alert(msg)
     }, "json");

$.getJSON("StudentFunctions.aspx/GetGender", function(msg) { 
        alert(msg)
     });
```

The three functions above doesn't even trigger the .Net function, but if I remove the "json" part from `$.post` and `$.get`, they at least calls the back-end function, but of course, doesn't return json.

Also, another question that I feel foolish for not understanding, but when I get the json response in the `$.ajax` function, what does that object (here called `msg`) look like? `msg.d` does the trick for me, but I don't know why. Is there a specification somewhere?

Comment: when you're using `$.ajax`, how the response object look like? can you put it here?

Comment: Take a look at http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ and http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/. It explains why the full `$.ajax()` method is required.

Comment: @StevenVondruska Thanks, that explains it. Seems like the ASP.NET framework needs the contentType as well. Also, drilling down a little in the pages you sent got me the answer to the msg.d question. If you want to formalize an answer I'll tag you as correct. Otherwise I might write something up later.

Comment: I added an answer so others may benefit from it!

Comment: Thanks, I got a little confused with answers from two different Stevens. Thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming the called function from jQuery is a `WebMethod`.

According to [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) the `WebMethod` requires the AJAX request to be a HTTP POST (unless disable this protection), and contain the content type HTTP header `application/json`. If that HTTP Header is missing, ASP.NET will reject the request.

Because of that requirement, `$.get()`, and `$.post()` don't work because they are convenience methods which don't always contain the required content type. So you need to use the `$.ajax()`, so the content type HTTP header can always be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it "just won't work," but at least I can tell you why.  If you download the dev (non-compressed) version of jquery and drill into the post function, you'll see that internally it's just a helper function to call the ajax function that works.  However, it *does not* include the contentType, nor does it allow you to set it!  This is the code:

```
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
```

As you can see, there is no contentType.  You can replicate the same failure by removing contentType from the ajax method.  So there you have it - but at least you know you're not losing anything other than slightly prettier code.